# How to query the dedupe ratios for Exagrid shares?

Tags: veeam, exagrid

This information is available in the web management GUI, but I'd like to get this information for use in a Powershell script that will use those values, and I'd prefer to not have to figure out how to scrape the website if I don't have to. Does anyone know if there's a file on the Exagrid unit, or a command that can be run, that will expose this info? For each given share, I'd like to know the current dedupe ratio.

My desired end-result is to combine this with Veeam's dedupe numbers, so I can have a start-to-finish dedupe number for my backup jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my answer from Exagrid support:

Mostly no.

The workaround that is better than scraping HTML : I can log into the web GUI Summary page and click the "export" link at the top of the page which will give me an XML document, so of course I could grab that with cURL or similar in Powershell and then parse it for what I want.

Edit - with the latest patch, I can confirm that this XML file contains the data. Instructions from their engineer :

> ```
>      <share name="BOSSQL1" totalBackupData="3884623968491" consuming="1225642477525"
> ```
>
> Just divide totalBackupData="3884623968491" By 
>   consuming="1225642477525" and you have your deduplication rate.